# How to create a button to select all checkbuttons

Tags: python, list, checkbox, tkinter

I want to create a list of checkboxes in Python with TkInter and try to select all checkboxes with a button.

```py
from tkinter import *
def create_cbuts():
for i in cbuts_text:
    cbuts.append(Checkbutton(root, text = i).pack())

def select_all():
    for j in cbuts:
        j.select()

root = Tk()
cbuts_text = ['a','b','c','d']
cbuts = []
create_cbuts()
Button(root, text = 'all', command = select_all()).pack()
mainloop()
```

I fear that he does not fill the list `cbuts`:

```py
cbuts.append(Checkbutton(root, text = i).pack())
```

Comment: `Checkbutton(root, text=i).pack()` doesn't return what you think it does.

Comment: yes it doesn't return an object for the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
Button(root, text = 'all', command = select_all()).pack()
```

with:

```
Button(root, text='all', command=select_all).pack()
```

---

`Checkbutton(root, text = i).pack()` returns you `None`. So you are actually appending `None`s to your list. What you need to do is: append the instance of `Button` not the value which `.pack()` returns (`None`)

Comment: This doesn't solve the whole problem. See my comment on the question.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I saw only the `command` part. I'll edit my answer. :)

Comment: Aaah, ok that makes sense. The method `.pack()`returns `None`

Comment: Which development environment do you prefer for python. Because I don't like the debuging mode from idle.

Comment: I'm using JetBrains PyCharm to develop python, It's great

Answer (score 5):

Here is the correct code

```py
from tkinter import *

def create_cbuts():
    for index, item in enumerate(cbuts_text):
        cbuts.append(Checkbutton(root, text = item))
        cbuts[index].pack()

def select_all():
    for i in cbuts:
        i.select()

def deselect_all():
    for i in cbuts:
        i.deselect()

root = Tk()

cbuts_text = ['a','b','c','d']
cbuts = []
create_cbuts()
Button(root, text = 'all', command = select_all).pack()
Button(root, text = 'none', command = deselect_all).pack()
mainloop()
```